# Synchronise folders on different Macs using rsync

Tags: macos, network, rsync

I am trying to synchronise two different folders using rsync. I have copied all the data worth 4Tb from a network share to an external hdd using `rsync -v -r /source /destination`. Now I need to run regular backup to sync both the locations. Can anyone suggest rsync command which I can use to synchronise both the folders.

Comment: By synchronize, you mean that changes can occur both on the network share and on the external HDD and you want to sync them both ways?

Comment: @patrix Yeah the destination folder should get updated from the source folder when i use the rsync command. So after running the command it should look for those files which has been updated on the network share and copy it on the destination.

Comment: I think that the best way to do that is using cron. In cron you can specify to execute rsync all days at 8.00 am and 8.00 pm (for example). Doing that way you will have always a copy in both of them.

Comment: @huseinasj: could you please completly reply to @patrix question. You have 2 locations of data: a `/source` and a `/destination`. When you talk of synchronisation, do you mean a one-way: `source → destination` or a two-way: `source ⟷ destination`? The **both** within your final question is leading to  a clear confusion.

Comment: Note that you will need to copy extended attributes as well for full functionality

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to continue to use `rsync` so as to maintain `/destination` synchronized with `/source`.

1st run:

```
rsync -avE /source /destination
```

next runs:

```
rsync -avE /source /destination
```

The `-a` option = `--archive` == `-rlptgoD`.

The `-E` option means copy extended attributes and ACL, and is mandatory on HFS+ filesystems.

**Warning**: the standard version of `rsync` on OS X, version 2.6.9 (see `rsync --version`) still
have problems with extended attributes.
These problems will be shown thanks to the `-v` option.

A verification of the output of `rsync` is mandatory.

This version 2.6.9 is too old and causing too many problems.

---

I advise any user willing to maintain in sync directories between
different Macs (or between a Mac and another Unix machine) to install
`rsync` version 3.1.2.

Here is the method I use:

1. install MacPorts: [MacPorts home page](https://www.macports.org/)

   - go to the [Quickstart section](https://www.macports.org/install.php), install `Xcode`
   - choose the right version to install (Mavericks, Yosemite or El Capitan)
2. Upgrade your PATH so as to find the `port` command in it
   for example, I installed it in `/local/bin` and modified my PATH
   like this:

   ```
   PATH=/local/bin:${PATH}
   export PATH
   ```
3. Install `rsync 3.1.2`:

   ```
   port install rsync
   ```

With this version of `rsync`, the right options to use will be:

```
rsync -avAX /source /destination
```

and if you read me thus far, you are pretty good enough now to read

```
man rsync
```

to get the light from the source.

Comment: Can you provide (or link to) a simple instruction guide to install rsync 3.1.2 for those of us not very familiar with Terminal? Is this method reliable? http://gaborhargitai.hu/upgrade-rsync-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: Yes that is a pretty simple and correct documentation. But be warned, you have to get familiar with not `Terminal` but command line interface if you want to improve command line environnment.

Comment: rsync 3.1.2 is also available from [homebrew](http://brew.sh) and you might find it simpler to install. Just these two lines: `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"` and `brew install rsync`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I ran the homebrew install, which was successful. But when I did the second command, install rsync, I got this:  "Error: No available formula with the name "rsync" 
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
These similarly named formulae were found:
grsync                     librsync                   vdirsyncer "

Homebrew then suggested I run the command "brew install homebrew/dupes/rsync" which I did. Installation seemed to be successful but when I do rsync --version I still get 2.6.9  

How do I get 3.1.2 to take its place?

Comment: I tried running the original rsync install cmd again and got this:  brew install rsync
Warning: homebrew/dupes/rsync-3.1.2 already installed

Comment: Never mind.  I ran the cmds: brew tap homebrew/dupes then brew install rsync and all seems to be fine.  When I do rsync --version I get 3.1.2 :-)

Answer (score 0):

### June, 2022 Update

As @dan suggested in [his answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/248732/149366), using the ancient 2.6.9 version of `rsync` is an exercise in frustration and confusion. If you use `rsync` on relatively *modern* versions of mac os, you will encounter issues with respect to preserving ACLs and Extended Attributes.

You can peruse the [release history of `rsync`](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/NEWS#3.0.0). You can review the changes for each release (currently ver 3.2.4 released April, 2022). You may also notice that version 2.6.9 (released 6 Nov 2006) was followed by version 3.0.0 on 1 Mar 2008. Ver 3.0.0 contained many significant changes, most notably:

1. Enhancements for `xattr` & `ACL` options in support of OS X users, &
2. Adoption of [GPLv3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License#Version_3).

Apple's decision to "freeze" `rsync` at 2.6.9 - just as these OS X enhancements were added seems to speak of their priorities. Apple will not abide GPLv3 even when it has substantial benefit for their customers.

#### Use `rsync` to preserve all macOS metadata

In the current version of `rsync` (ver 3.2.4), the following options have demonstrated their ability to accurately preserve extended attributes and ACLs across the *backup-restore cycle*:

```
% rsync -rlAXtgoD --fake-super /source/ /destination
```

Here's a summary of some useful options:

```
#  -r                   recursive; recurse into directories  
#  -l                   copy symlinks as symlinks  
#  --acls, -A           preserve ACLs (implies --perms, -p)  
#  --xattrs, -X         preserve extended attributes  
#  -t                   preserve modification times  
#  -g                   preserve group  
#  -o                   preserve owner  
#  -D                   preserve devices and special files  
#  -v                   increased verbosity; may be repeated  
#  -i                   itemize changes  
#  --fake-super         store/recover privileged attrs using xattrs (for ACLs & XATTRs)  
#  --dry-run            perform a trial run with no changes made
```

#### Debugging `rsync`:

`rsync` can create a mess if options are applied [*will-nilly*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/willy-nilly). It's a very good idea to make a [*dry run*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/dry%20run), and review `rsync`'s *proposed* changes before committing. `rsync` provides options that support that:

```
% rsync -rlAXtgoDivv --dry-run --fake-super /source/ /destination
```

The `-ivv` options are useful for debugging, providing a detailed accounting of the changes. Using `ivv` with `--dry-run` will reliably inform you of what's going to happen before it happens.

##### Addendum:

This [GitHub *"recipe"*](https://github.com/seamusdemora/seamusdemora.github.io/blob/master/RsyncWithNoMetaDataLoss.md) contains a couple of scripts and a procedure that may be useful for those who wish to  verify that `rsync` has faithfully replicated all extended attributes and ACLs.

Answer (score -2):

Easiest way to update rsync on MacOS Mojave as described at the following link.

https://bayton.org/2018/07/how-to-update-rsync-on-mac-os-high-sierra/

1. Open the terminal and paste the command:

   ```
   /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
   ```
2. Now you are ready to install the new Rsync version, and can do so as follows:

   ```
   brew install rsync
   ```
3. Once completed, you should sign out and back in to MacOS.

When entering the command below, you will see now that you are using rsync 3.1.3 (at time of writing), instead of rsync 2.6.9. You are no longer running a 12 year old version of Rsync!

```
<pre>rsync --version
rsync  version 3.1.3  protocol version 31</pre>
```

As simple as that.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: My reply included the text information needed. See original. "Easiest way to update rsync on MacOS Mojave."

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but the answer should actually contain an answer, not just directions towards the answer. Please quote the most relevant part of an important link, also in case the page goes offline. For more information, see [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/222623)